# angularjs, how to bind data after redirection to another page?

Tags: angularjs, post

I am calling my controller function from page1, as well as redirecting to page2 with ng-click method. The code is getting executed and data. Here is my method in controller class.

```
<a href="FlightSearch/Search/SearchResult" class="btn_search" ng-click="SearchFlight()">SEARCH </a>

    $scope.SearchFlight = function () { 
    var AirAvailabilityRQ =
    {         
        OriginLocation: $scope.DepartureCity.LocationCode,
        DestinationLocation: $scope.DestinationCity.LocationCode,
        DepartureDateTime: $scope.travel_date,
        ConversationId: "",
        MessageId: "",
        AirLineCode: [],
        PreferencesCabin: "E",
        MaxStopsQuantity: "0",
        IsIgnoreCodeShareFlight: true,
        Token: "",
        TenantId: "",
        Type: ""
    };

    SearchResultService.getSearchresult(AirAvailabilityRQ, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {                
            if (value.JourneyType == "Forward") {
                $scope.ForwardFlightList = value.AirFlightDetails;
            }
            else {
                $scope.ReturnFlightList = value.AirFlightDetails;
            }
        });
    })
}
```

the code for service:

```
searchResult.factory("SearchResultService", function ($http) {
return {
    getSearchresult: function (data,callback) {
        return $http.post("/FlightSearch/Search/BeginSearch",data).success(callback);
    }
}
});
```

My method hits the MVC controller thru SearchResultService. I am getting data in .CS code, but I am not getting data in my angularJS controller althouth data is returned. When I use  console.log(response), I get nothing. Not even null, in browser console.

When the same page (page2) is executed on standalone basis, I can get data in angularJS the function, and I am able to bind it to the page.

So what is the mistake?

Comment: $http.post?? isn't it supposed to be a get method??

Comment: Actually, I am passing data as entity from angularJS function, thats why I made it post method. But let me change and check.

Comment: post and get depends upon the API, you can use http.get which will return the result of your post of entity :)

Comment: Sorry Alex, I cannot use get here, I am passing date and some other parameters, all in an entity.

Comment: Alex, I am unable to understand, you are saying get as well as post for the same method? what is the syntax for such a thing

Comment: i think you misunderstood what i meant was, if your api has a get method that takes in entity as an argument you use $http.get by sending the data. I suggest you to check in postman first sending the data and seeing the end result. And then, verify if the data you are sending actually returns anything from the api.

Comment: I am using postman daily. But Get method does not accept sending entity. When we select get, body becomes automatically disabled. I tried sending entity thru url in angularjs, the MVC controller received null in place of entity. There ends the matter.

Comment: So, I am back to my original question. When I am navigating from one page to another on click of a button, and I do a Post to hit the MVC controller, and I get data in the back end, how do I bind to my html page as I am not getting any data in angularJS function?